# Serialized Ajax Parameters not showing up in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, serialization, prototypejs

I am trying to access the parameters passed in my AJAX request, but when I try to print them out in PHP, nothing shows up. I know emailData is defined and correct, so that is not the problem.

Here is my current code:

```
function sendEmail(){
var emailData = $('emailForm').serialize(true);
new Ajax.Request("php/email.php",
    {
        method : "get",
        parameters : emailData,
        onFailure : ajaxFailure,
        onException : ajaxFailure
    }
);}
```

and in email.php

```
print_r($_GET);
```

**EDIT**

When I check to see if emailData is defined with an alert or console.log, I get the correct values I want, in the correct format for ajax parameters according to http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize.

**2nd EDIT**

Seems to work now. I haven't modified the code at all, but it seems to work now.

Comment: What library are you using? Are you using both jQuery and Prototype? If so, why?

Comment: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize. This is not a call to jQuery.

Comment: Test your PHP by calling it in a browser with your own parameters: http://mydomain.com/php/email.php?name=Jim&age=20 . See what it spits out. If that works, then there's a problem in the Ajax call.

Comment: edited tags to reflect `prototypjs` instead of `prototype`. Read the descriptions; `prototype` has a completely different meaning, and it's not the one you want.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Just joined, and I must have not read before using that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `onSuccess:` value. You're only checking for errors and exceptions.

Do something like:

```
function sendEmail(){
var emailData = $('emailForm').serialize(true);
new Ajax.Request("php/email.php",
    {
        method : "get",
        parameters : emailData,
        onFailure : ajaxFailure,
        onException : ajaxFailure,
        onSuccess : function() { alert("success!"); }
    }
);}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Of course, you'll want to do something more substantial, like `onSuccess : function(data) { alert(data); }`, so you can manipulate `data`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var emailData = $('#emailForm').serialize(true);
```

emailform is an id perhaps?

Comment: emailForm is an id. The serialization works as I said in the post. When I do console.log(emailData);, I get this: Object { to="a@ab.com, ", from="b@ab.com", subject="", more...}

Comment: have you checked in Firebug/fiddler what is being sent? Problem could be in your PHP code?